# I'm following an online advanced CV course but the code wouldn't run properly for me. These are the error messages I've gotten:

Tags: python, opencv, error-handling, face-recognition, cvzone

```
INFO: Created TensorFlow Lite XNNPACK delegate for CPU.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "e:\Coding\Python\Face_Reg\test.py", line 13, in <module>
    fingers = detector.fingersUp('*')
  File "C:\Users\aarav\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\cvzone\HandTrackingModule.py", line 111, in fingersUp
    myHandType = myHand["type"]
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

this is my code:

```
import cv2
import cvzone.SerialModule
from cvzone.HandTrackingModule import HandDetector

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
detector = HandDetector(maxHands = 1, detectionCon = 0.7)
#mySerial = cvzone.SerialObject("COM3", 9600, 1)
while True:
    success, img = cap.read()
    hands, img = detector.findHands(img)
    lmList, bbox = detector.findHands(img)
    if lmList:
        fingers = detector.fingersUp('*')
        print(fingers)
       # mySerial.sendData(fingers)
    cv2.imshow("Image", img)
    cv2.waitKey(1)
```

Hi! I was making a hand tracking software. When I click run the camera pops up but as soon as I put my hand in frame the thing shuts and gives  error

Comment: According to the [examples](https://github.com/cvzone/cvzone#examples)  `detector.fingersUp` expects a hand object, but you are passing a string `"*"`. You should do `detector.fingersUp(hands[0])` to pass the first hand object like in the example. Where did you get your code from?

Answer (score 0):

`HandDetector.fingersUp` expects a dictionary representing a hand, as returned by `HandDetector.findHands`.

A working example is provided below:

```py
import cv2
import cvzone.SerialModule
from cvzone.HandTrackingModule import HandDetector

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
detector = HandDetector(maxHands = 1, detectionCon = 0.7)
while True:
    success, img = cap.read()
    # The 'flipType' parameter flips the image, making it easier for some detections
    hands, img = detector.findHands(img, flipType=True)
    if hands:
        # Gets fingers for the first detected hand
        fingers = detector.fingersUp(hands[0])
        print(fingers)
       # mySerial.sendData(fingers)
    cv2.imshow("Image", img)
    cv2.waitKey(1)
```

Note: You might also want to take a look at the [project's github](https://github.com/cvzone#hand-tracking-module), as it contains detailed examples for hand tracking.

Answer (score -1):

The error you're seeing originates from this part of your code:

```
fingers = detector.fingersUp('*')
```

The error message:

```
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

indicates that the fingersUp function is trying to access string indices with non-integer values.

The problem is likely **how you're calling the fingersUp method**. Typically, fingersUp would need the landmarks of the detected hand, but you're passing it a string ('*').

The proper way to call the fingersUp method is by passing the landmarks of the detected hand.

Here's a corrected version of your code:

```
import cv2
import cvzone.SerialModule
from cvzone.HandTrackingModule import HandDetector

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
detector = HandDetector(maxHands=1, detectionCon=0.7)

while True:
    success, img = cap.read()
    hands, img = detector.findHands(img)

    # This will give the landmarks of the detected hand
    lmList, bboxInfo = detector.findPosition(img)
    
    if lmList:
        fingers = detector.fingersUp()
        print(fingers)
    cv2.imshow("Image", img)
    cv2.waitKey(1)
```

Notice **I removed the argument from fingersUp()** since the method uses the most recent hand landmarks internally.

**Run the modified code** and see if it works for you. If any other issues arise, **double-check the documentation** or examples from your CV course to ensure you're using the methods correctly.